# geany cannot import pygame while I can import it in terminal

Tags: python, pygame

I've just install pygame in my linux ubuntu16.04 for learning python.

When I try to import pygame in geany, it doesn't work,it shows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ttest2.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pygame
ImportError: No module named 'pygame'
```

When I import pygame in my terminal it works.

I don't know why. How can I import pygame in my geany?

Comment: Do you have both python2 and python3 installed? Is geany configured to use the right one?

Comment: You may have installed `pygame` for a different version of python than the one geany is configured to use.

Comment: actually, I do have python2 and python3, but I can import pygame in both versions in terminal.

Comment: Can you import any other modules in geany? Or is this only happening for `pygame`

Comment: Maybe I didn't install pygame properly.Because when I try to uninstall pygame in terminal, it tells me it does not exist. @ Farhan.K

Comment: That's probably the issue then. You should install it using `pip` if you can

Answer (score 0):

Geany uses the lib. Pygame is installed for Python 2.7, not 3.x, unlike other environments. So you have to install it, too, for Python 2.7:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
pip install pygame
```